# How to block website in Mobiles developed in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Javascript to block website in Mobile browsers which is done, but if selected Desktop Site in Mobile Browser, Website is displaying. How to Stop it from loading in Desktop Site irrespective of any browser. I am not familiar with php javascript is there anything i am missing in this code? Can anyone help me out yrr.

```
    @extends('layouts.auth')
    @section('page-title')
        {{__('Login')}}
    @endsection
    @php
        $logo=asset(Storage::url('uploads/logo/'));
    @endphp
    @section('content')
    
        <div class="login-contain">
            <div class="login-inner-contain">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="{{$logo.'/logo.png'}}" class="navbar-brand-img auth-logo" alt="logo">
                </a>
                <div class="login-form">
                    <div class="page-title"><h5>{{__('Login')}}</h5></div>
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email" class="form-control-label">{{__('Email')}}</label>
                            <input class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" id="email" type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>
                            @error('email')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                            @enderror
    
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password" class="form-control-label">{{__('Password')}}</label>
                            <input class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" id="password" type="password" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">
                            @error('password')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                            @enderror
    
                        </div>
    
                        @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                            <a href="{{ route('password.request') }}" class="text-xs text-primary">{{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}</a>
                        @endif
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-login">{{__('Login')}}</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
    
                <h5 class="copyright-text">
                    {{(Utility::getValByName('footer_text')) ? Utility::getValByName('footer_text') :  __('Copyright HRMGo') }} {{ date('Y') }}
                </h5>
                <div class="all-select">
                    <a href="#" class="monthly-btn">
                        <span class="monthly-text py-0">{{__('Change Language')}}</span>
                        <select class="select-box select2" onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" id="language">
                            @foreach(Utility::languages() as $language)
                                <option @if($lang == $language) selected @endif value="{{ route('login',$language) }}">{{Str::upper($language)}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endsection


  
<script>
    (function(a,b)
    {
        if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))window.location=b
        })
        (navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera,   
        'http://www.google.com/mobile');
</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? The given code does not contain any checks for a browser detection

Comment: Why do you care if it's a mobile or not??

Comment: @NicoHaase  [Linkl](http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile) i used this javascript concept, but it is loading in Desktop site in mobile browser but blocking in mobile view.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase Done updating Question

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is the user-agent, HTTP header check out this documentation from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)

Comment: [link](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/mobile) i have tried this so far it is working .... i want to display a custom error page now.

Comment: here is this article, it will help you with that [link](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-create-custom-error-page-in-laravel-8example.html)

Comment: If i am doing Desktop site in mobile then website is loading. Any idea.